# Heroku - Django raise TemplateDoesNotExist(name) exception, but template is not needed in requested action

Tags: django, templates, heroku

I got a strange heroku behavior.

My code:

```
def generate(request, page_id):
    page = get_object_or_404(Page, pk=page_id)

    response = HttpResponse(page.content)
    response['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'

    return response
```

works as I expect on dev, but on heroku it raises an exception

```
GET test.herokuapp.com/generate/1 dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=908ms status=500 bytes=59
2012-07-29T19:20:06+00:00 app[web.1]:     raise TemplateDoesNotExist(name)
2012-07-29T19:20:06+00:00 app[web.1]: TemplateDoesNotExist: 500.html
```

and returns proper output ;) Only this one action is wrong. Other actions where I use

```
return render_to_response('front/home.html')
```

are Ok. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code throws an unhandled exception, which, outside of debug mode, makes Django display an error page that uses template `500.html`. You apparently have no such template, so the exception handler raises another exception, which is the one you're seeing.

Comment: So you suggest that I first got an exception and then 500 (yes it is not defined yet). Yes?

Comment: @mrok: That's right. You got an exception, and the exception handler tried to serve page from `500.html` template, which then raised the exception you're seeing.

Comment: Thanks for help, I was trying to figure out what caused this exception. When I got rid of ideas I created 500.html template - it helped.